# Chrome audit: Form elements do not have associated labels

Tags: html, google-chrome-devtools

I'm receiving this error after auditing my product page in Chrome:

> Form elements do not have associated labels

Failing Elements

`input#quantity_5ce535030e171.input-text.qty.text`

`input#woocommerce-product-search-field-0.search-field`

Labels clearly indicate `input` tags with `for` attribute.

**Element #1:**

```
<div class="quantity">
<label class="screen-reader-text" for="quantity_5ce535030e171">My product name</label>
<input type="number" id="quantity_5ce535030e171" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="1" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" size="4" inputmode="numeric">
</div>
```

**Element #2:**

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="woocommerce-product-search" action="https://example.com/example-product/">
<label class="screen-reader-text" for="woocommerce-product-search-field-0">Search for:</label>
<input type="search" id="woocommerce-product-search-field-0" class="search-field" placeholder="Search products…" value="" name="s">
<button type="submit" value="Search">Search</button>
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product">
</form>
```

Is there anything incorrect in html or Chrome gives false errors?

Comment: Your code seems OK to me. You could try nesting the `<input>` as a child of `<label>`.

Comment: I've nested associated `input` tag as child of `label`, unfortunately I'm still receiving the same error. Everything on up-to-date Chrome. Perhaps it's this issue? https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/8435

Comment: That does seem relevant. If you install the Lighthouse extension you might be able to check if the issue is fixed now. I believe the extension is running Lighthouse v5.

Comment: I've tested Lighthouse extension and indeed this error is no more. Hopefully this gets shipped to browser soon.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was a bug fixed in axe-core 3.2.0 according to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-core/issues/1578), but the fix is still not incorporated into Lighthouse as of Chrome version 75.0.3770.142.

Lighthouse uses Axe for the accessibility portion of its audit, but you can run Axe as a stand-alone [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/axe/lhdoppojpmngadmnindnejefpokejbdd?hl=en-US). I ran the stand-alone extension (version 3.8.0 with axe-core 3.2.2) on a site I'm working on that uses visually hidden form labels and it passed; whereas Lighthouse still failed with the error you mentioned. From what I can tell, based on the learn more links from audit results, Lighthouse is using version 3.1 of axe-core.

As long as styles for `.screen-reader-text` don't use `display:none;`, `visibility: hidden;`, or  zero out the width or height, it should pass the stand-alone Axe extension audit.